# Do I interpret "bad looping" code correctly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made it a habit to program "looping" code in the manner shown bellow. I am a self taught coder, and I am just wondering if it is really necessary or not. (This example is in Unity C#):

Example:
Will this:

```
void Update()
{
 //GameOver Procedure

       if(shipCurrentHP <= 0 && GameOver == false)
        {
            StartCoroutine(BlowUp());
            GameOver = true;
        }
}
```

Be any better than this?:

```
void Update()
{
     //GameOver Procedure

        if(shipCurrentHP <= 0)
        {
           StartCoroutine(BlowUp());
           GameOver = true;
        }
}
```

Comment: That's not better nor worse. That's just different. You're missing a condition on the second case, so you can't compare those two procedures.

Comment: A thing you could do though, is write `!GameOver` instead of `GameOver == false`

Comment: It is better not in terms of performance or anything. In second case you will start the blow up coroutines in every frame which is bad.

Comment: Thank you: But if (shipCurrentHP <= 0)  >> Then Game is over... So basically is it necessary to check for the second case, just so that the "loop" can stop executing?

Comment: Does `StartCoroutine(BlowUp())` change `shipCurrentHP`? If not, then the condition is still going to be true next time `Update` is called...

Comment: @AliKanat Thank you, that's what I wanted to know. I didn't know the coroutine will start every frame. I thought they execute only once... Thank you! :)

Comment: @ArthurAttout Thank you! So will !GameOver be better syntax or actually influence performance?

Comment: Both `GameOver == false` and `!GameOver` have the same translation by the compiler, there is no performance alteration. This is just a more common practice to write it this way

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you! No it does not. So then the first example is correct I assume. :)

Comment: @ArthurAttout Okay thank you. It is quicker, and quicker is simpler, so ill use it next time. :)

Comment: In large areas of code where there are a lot of statements, people tend to use `(Statement == false)`, because it might be better readable in some cases. Though simple statements are most commonly used with the exclamation mark.

Comment: @Livo I'm not aware of any case in which evaluating a boolean with `==` makes it 'more readable'.

Comment: Well I've worked on quite some games and there are those cases where a function will return a Boolean and intuitively you expect the if statement to act on true, so explicitly stating that you expect false, makes it easier for others in your team and also your self to make a fast scan through the code and understand what the code is suppose to do.
Also when the function name or boolean have wierd names, I tend to even `== true`. I don't always have influence over how names of variables or functions are and sometimes those confuse me. Simply stating `== fase` or `== true`, makes this go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example will start another coroutine in every frame after the condidion is initially met, it will most likely just eat up all the RAM of the machine if the user does nothing after that point. Generally doing stuff in Update should be avoided unless you are doing somethign that actually needs to execute every frame

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was wondering, and also I agree, this script was used with OnTriggerEnter{}, but this is just an example :).